# Reading label Id

Tags: jquery

I'm having a table in which i'm creating a label dynamically.

```
'<td>' + '<label for="Name" id = ' + value + '>' + text + '</label></td>'
```

I want to retrieve the id of the label and I`m doing the following which is not working:
How can I get the Id of the label?

```
function ReadNames() {
            $('#Table tr').each(function() {
                NameID.push($(this).find('label').val());
            });   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple `tr`'s and each has at least one (or exactly one) label

```
function ReadNames () {
    $('#Table tr td label').each(function () {
        NameID.push(this.id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, <del>you'll have to</del> you should correct the markup and include quotes for the id:

```
'<td><label for="Name" id="' + value + '">' + text + '</label></td>'
```

Next, `$('label').attr('id')` should get you the id.

Comment: Quotes are often optional around attribute values. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: @David Technically yes, okay, but only if the ID conforms to certain constraints (possible characters). Especially when constructing elements dynamically, like the OP, and even when not, you should always go for quotes. It is even recommended in the article you link to. :)

Comment: All of the characters allowed in an id ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name ) are on the list of "No quotes needed" ;)

Comment: That said, I'd build my elements with DOM rather than strings, which eliminates the need to worry about quotes (since using standard DOM will deal with escaping and so on for you)

Comment: @David But what if the OP used XHTML? :)

Comment: Then I'd rant about how silly it is to use XHTML in a world where we have to support IE < 9 :)